# C: Trying to restore signal handlers with sigaction but not succeeding.

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, operating-system

I'm writing a small program in C, (running on ubuntu). The first time the program receives Ctrl+C, I want the signal to be ignored, but the second time (after 10 seconds of waiting), I want the original action to be restored (and the signal not be ignored). So I have something like this:

```
void (*sold)(int);
struct sigaction s;
sold = s.sa_handler;
s.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
sigaction(SIGINT,&s,NULL);
sleep(10)
s.sa_handler = sold; //(this could be replaced by s.sa_handler = *sold and it doenst make a difference)
```

The program seems to ignore SIGINT just fine, but it doesn't revert back.., as in it doesn't restore the old handler. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: instead of assigning the handle to NULL, how about write a small function to handle the CTRL-C according to your own condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to restore the old signal handler, you need to actually save and restore the old handler:

```
struct sigaction newHandler;
struct sigaction oldHandler;
memset(&newHandler, 0, sizeof(newHandler));
sigemptyset( &newHandler.sa_mask );
newHandler.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
sigaction(SIGINT, &newHandler, &oldHandler );
sleep( 10 );
sigaction(SIGINT, &oldHandler, NULL );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the signal disposition again, you must call `sigaction()` again (or another function that serves the same purpose).  Assigning a new handler to the `struct sigaction` with which you previously set the signal handler has no special effect.